How to use replacetext or any other processor to achieve the below scenario
{
"Id":100,
"name":"jcb",
"Keyboard":[cpu|usage,mem|usage,disk|usage]
}
How to convert this to perfect json I mean
Keyboard":["cpu|usages","mem|usages","disk|usages"].  Like this remain json same
I am trying with replacetext suggest with any other processor

Do you mean reurning of {  "Keyboard":["cpu|usages","mem|usages","disk|usages"] } , eg. with curly brace wrappers ?

If so, the you can try with JoltTransformJSON processor.

you can use ExecuteGroovyScript with LAX parser and then build a correct json.
LAX mode allows keys with no quotes, keys with single quotes, strings elements in JSON with no quotes or single quotes.
Script to use in ExecuteGroovyScript
import groovy.json.*

def ff = session.get()
if(!ff) return
ff.write{rawIn, rawOut->
    //parse flowfile with LAX parser
    def obj = new JsonSlurper().setType(JsonParserType.LAX).parse(rawIn, "UTF-8")
    //write true json into output
    rawOut.withWriter("UTF-8"){ new JsonBuilder(obj).writeTo(it) }
}
REL_SUCCESS << ff

